# Windows 8 ghc-mod installation fails

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

I'm trying to work on Haskell in IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 8.

I installed the latest Haskell plugin, and found that it requires ghc.exe, cabal.exe and ghc-mod.exe prepared. Haskell Platform (x64) originally contains ghc.exe and cabal.exe, so what I need in order to make the plugin work is ghc-mod.exe.

Just as many guides say, I tried installing it through cabal like this:

```
cabal install ghc-mod
```

It failed installing haskell-src-exts in the middle of the process, so I installed happy and tried the same command again. Then it succeeded to install src-exts, yet not ghc-mod. Cabal produced this error log:

```
Building ghc-mod-0.3.0...
Preprocessing executable 'ghc-mod' for ghc-mod-0.3.0...
[1 of 6] Compiling Param            ( Param.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-67612b7f\build\ghc-mod\ghc-mod-tmp\Param.o )
[2 of 6] Compiling Lang             ( Lang.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-67612b7f\build\ghc-mod\ghc-mod-tmp\Lang.o )
[3 of 6] Compiling List             ( List.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-67612b7f\build\ghc-mod\ghc-mod-tmp\List.o )
[4 of 6] Compiling Check            ( Check.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-67612b7f\build\ghc-mod\ghc-mod-tmp\Check.o )
[5 of 6] Compiling Browse           ( Browse.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-67612b7f\build\ghc-mod\ghc-mod-tmp\Browse.o )

Browse.hs:41:72:
    Not in scope: data constructor `ExplicitForall'
    Perhaps you meant `ExplicitForAll' (imported from Language.Haskell.Exts.Extension)
```

This doesn't make sense to me at all. What can I do?

Comment: `ghc-mod-0.3.0` is ancient! The current version is `5.2.1.2`. Try installing something recent.

Comment: But how do you do it through cabal?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka Just checking: did you do `cabal update` first?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka You can specify the version to be installed on the command line: `cabal install ghc-mod-5.2.1.2`. Perhaps the [user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-1.14.0/doc/users-guide/installing-packages.html) or `cabal help` will be useful in the future.

Comment: @AndrewC Yes I did. Maybe I have forgot. @user2407038 Thank you for the latest number,, I succeeded to install ghc-mod.exe and ghc-modi.exe. And now I ran into another question: In IntelliJ I set paths of `cabal executable`, `cabal data path`, `ghc-mod executable` and `ghc-modi executable`. Every time I open up the project, IntelliJ claims "`ghc-modi failed with error: NG BUG: GMECabalFlags (GMEString "extractField: failed extracting configFlags from input, input contained \`configFlags'? False")`". What does this mean?